# Mortgage interest income tax deduction during year with a principal residence change

Tags: united-states, mortgage, income-tax, tax-deduction

In 2010 my residency changed from the home I own to a home I'm renting, but I owned the mortgaged home all year.  Is the deductable amount of mortgage interest paid pro-rated based on the date I moved?  This is unclear to me (or I'm optimistic I can claim the full amount of interest for 2010) because I often see the principal residence rule using the phrase "majority of the time".  I spent 75% of the year in the mortgaged house and 25% in the rental.

An IRS pub number, section, and paragraph would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you still own the mortgaged home?

Comment: @MrChrister yes

Comment: After checking IRS Pub 936, http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p936.pdf, this counts as a second home not rented. The mortgage interest is fully deductible whether it is my primary residence (main home) or not.  I did not know mortgage interest on a second home was deductible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.irs.gov/publications/p936/ar02.html#en_US_2010_publink1000229891

If you still own it, you get to deduct all of it.

In my taxes I did online with TaxAct, it asked if I lived there or not and it just mattered which form it filed for me.  With having tenants it was a 'business' form and I assume it would be a standard schedule A for personal.  Either way the deductions are still mine to take.

Comment: I commented above before I saw your answer.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @mghicks - also answer your own question if you find the answer first.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. If it wasn't rented, it's deductible as a schedule A home mortgage interest.
If it was rented, you go into Schedule E land, still a deduction along with any/every expense incurred.